# How to visualize the matrix transformation?

Tags: matrix, visualization

Actually, the question is related to [this topic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46392/visualization-of-matrix-transformations), but it is no expected answer there. And it seems the following answer leads to another direction. As we know, we can visualize the vector by `VectorPlot` with some arrow:

```
VectorPlot[{y, -x}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

The vector `{y, -x}` will act on every point. I want to visualize a matrix transformation like this way. I mean the matrix will act on every vector(its coordinate), the arrow represents the orientation of the result vector, and the length represents the norm of the result vector. But I don't know how to avoid those result vector overlapping. Any idea to do it?

Comment: Could you provide an example of a transformation?

Comment: Can you manually adjust the value of the `VectorScale` option for `VectorPlot` to get what you want?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  Are you asking "Which matrix when multiplied by $(x,y)^T$ results in $(y,-x)$?  If so, $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} y \\ -x \end{pmatrix}.$

Comment: If you are asking how to keep all the vectors the same size, to avoid overlapping, you could divide each non-zero vector by its norm.  In that case, the plot would only show direction, not magnitude.

Comment: @C.E. Sorry for late response, the network is broke here. The bills have give the right answer..

Comment: @mjw Thanks very very much..

Comment: @yode, you are welcome.  Agreed, the answer below is excellent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can visualize the action of a matrix on any element directly using `VectorPlot`. For example, consider the action of the matrix $a$:

```
a = {{1, -2}, {3, 3}};
VectorPlot[a.{x, y}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

[image: plot]

This shows how $a$ acts on elements of $R^2$. You can control the size of the arrows in the plot using `VectorScale -> 0.1`, or `VectorScale -> 0.05`.

Comment: Thanks very much... it is my expected answer surely..